# How to make one text box as enable and another is disabled?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code...
In this the one textbox is hidden and another is enable named(licence)..
While checking the checkbox the value of the checkbox need to set into the hidden textbox and enable it...
And enabled textbox need to be disabled...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('input[name=licence3]').blur(function(){
    var third = $(this).val();
    var first = $('input[name=licence1]').val();
    var second = $('input[name=licence2]').val();
    
    
    
    $('input[name=licence]').val(first+second+third);
    
  });
  
  $("#check").click(function() {
    $('input[name=licence1]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence2]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence3]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence]').val("");
    
    // Here i need another coding While clicking checkbox 
//the checkbox value should set to the hidden textbox value which is in same name...
    //And the Enabled textbox should be disable
  });
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="licence" value="" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="text" name="licence1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="licence2" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="licence3" value="" />
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" value="Applied">
  <br>
  <br>
  Final<input type="text" name="licence" value="" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
  if(this.checked){
         var value = $('input[name=licence1]').val()+$('input[name=licence2]').val()+$('input[name=licence3]').val();
         $('input:hidden').val(this.val(value)).prop('disabled',!this.checked);
         $('input:enabled').val('').prop('disabled',this.checked);
  }
});
```

I couldnot able to understand your question completely, I assume that when checkbox is checked, you require 4 things

1. set the checkbox value to input:hidden field.
2. Disable all the enabled input fields.
3. Empty the enabled input values.
4. Display the hidden input field with value equal to sum of the 3 input fields

Comment: Sorry for the trouble... The the text box which is named (licence) only disable and enable the same named textbox... Assign the checkbox value into the hidden textbox field

Comment: check the above 4 things which I noted. Hope it helps

Comment: Pleasure to help. Seems you are newbie to jquery, long way to go dude. Happy learning and Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable input tag using

```
 $('input[name=licence]').attr('disabled', 'true')
```

Coudn't understand your actual requirement,hope the following snippet helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('input[name=licence3]').blur(function(){
    var third = $(this).val();
    var first = $('input[name=licence1]').val();
    var second = $('input[name=licence2]').val();
    
    
    
    $('input[name=licence]').val(first+second+third);
      $('input[name=licence]').attr('disabled','true')
  });
  
  $("#check").click(function() {
    $('input[name=licence1]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence2]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence3]').val("");
    $('input[name=licence]').val("");
    
    // Here i need another coding While clicking checkbox 
//the checkbox value should set to the hidden textbox value which is in same name...
    //And the Enabled textbox should be disable
  });
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="licence" value="" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="text" name="licence1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="licence2" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="licence3" value="" />
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" value="Applied">
  <br>
  <br>
  Final<input type="text" name="licence" value="" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks... But the hidden text box should be display and enable and also get those three textbox values